# eddy current brakes

Tags: power-electronics, solenoid, electric-machine, braking

I am trying to make an eddy brake prototype It works perfectly using a permanent magnet, but I have to make it using an electromagnet which is not working. I am using a solenoid purchased from Amazon and a silver plate.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The moving plate needs to be in quite a strong magnetic field, this is why a permanent magnet with opposite poles either side of the moving plate (and with as small an air gap as possible) is so effective. The only air gap in the magnetic circuit should, ideally, be the one that encloses the moving plate.

Comment: Your question is very poor. Show photos, diagrams, etc., of your prototype with dimensions, calculated and measured braking effort. Then show your layout for the electro-magnet. Show where you expect the magnetic flux to flow. And delete 'Help me' from your post so it doesn't look so dumb.

Comment: Your edit question has lost the link to the product details and doesn't show the permanent magnet setup (which should include where the poles are on the magnet) and doesn't give details on the what you expect and what you got in each scenario. Please edit and fix.

Answer (score 4):

Your electromagnet may work if you ad "back iron" on the opposite side of the plate as shown below. Make the air gap as small as possible.

[image]

An alternative would be to sandwich the back iron to the conductive plate. Make the moving part two pieces, an iron piece and a conductive piece firmly attached to the surface of the iron that faces the magnet.